# the major version number of shared library

Tags: linux

i compiled a program, it depends tiff shared library, on my computer, the version of library is libtiff.so.4, but it couldn't run on another computer(the major version number of tiff is 5, libtiff.so.5).
anybody have a good approach to resolve this problem.
thanks

```
linux-gate.so.1 => (0xb76f3000)       
libtiff.so.4 => not found   
libQtGui.so.4 => /home/ken/wpsenv/3rdparty/qt/lib/libQtGui.so.4 (0xb69cb000)
```

Comment: Have you tried installing libtiff.so.4 on your target computer?

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the shared library version (called "soname") is that is reflects binary compatibility. When your program is linked to libtiff.so.4 , then that's the version it needs. libtiff.so.5 would be a newer library that is incompatible with libtiff.so.4. (The version numbers here doesn't need to match the offical version of the project, the .4 and .5 are supposed to reflect the binary backwards compatibility level).

You have 2 choices:

- Install the required libtiff library. Many distributions will provide different versions of a library that can co-exist.
- Recompile the application so it links to libtiff.so.5

Comment: i only use several functions in libtiff.so (libtiff.so.4 and libtiff.so.5 are same for these functions).   i can't recompile it for so.5.   my idea is that if customer computer has so.4 or so.5, it both runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Statically link libtiff.a to your program if thats an option and libtiff.a is present on your system.

gcc main.c path-to-libtiff.a -o myprog